# Re-installation of APK does not works and through an error "App Not Installed"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin Forms .netstandard application with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and apk generated from it gets installed for the first time but when i uninstall the application and then try to install the same apk it does not work and through an error that "App not installed". Even if i clean the device before installing it does not works.

I am running 
VS 2017 15.8.3
Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.122203,
Xamarin.Android.Support libraries 2.5.4.0.2,
NETStandard Library 2.0.3

Even this happens even if I create new application with everything updated it issue prevails.

Please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: To go to Settings -> apps -> do you see your app listed if yes -> uninstall for all user -> delete bin/obj-> rebuild -> deploy

Comment: Hi Saket, I have tried this but it did not worked.

Comment: Solved it by uninstalling and then installing Android SDK